# Collection function fails to gather unique items when the item is a Number?

Tags: vba, excel

Im using the following Collection script which is working against each column. I have used the same script for 4 columns, and it works perfectly. However, 1 column is only filled with number values and thus fails to return anything. If I insert a text value in this reference field, they are returned as desired. The only thing I can think is that I need the number values need to be interpreted as a string first, then run through the collection?

Here's the code:

```
Sub list_gen_uni()

Sheets("xx").Select

 'Units/Item
 Dim UNI As New Collection


On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In Range("J2:J1000")
     UNI.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
     Next cell

On Error GoTo 0

For i = 1 To UNI.Count
 Cells(i + 1, "K") = UNI.Item(i)
 Next


Call list_gen_items


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the keys need to be text, so use CStr:

```
UNI.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
```